# Are there any public OpenCL C libraries?

Tags: opencl, opencl-c

The title says it all, but to be even clearer: I'm looking for libs / collections of OpenCL C (kernel) code, not libs that use / provide an interface to OpenCL. Also, my interest is not restricted to a specific use case. Therefore the question is intentionally vague.
Ideally, answers provide a name, description and link to projects that provide useful OpenCL C code snippets.

Edit: I will try to consolidate all answers here

- Samples from the [AMD APP SDK](https://github.com/ghostlander/AMD-APP-SDK/releases/tag/v2.9.1)
- Samples by [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl)
- Samples from the [Intel FPGA OpenCL SDK](https://www.intel.la/content/www/xl/es/software/programmable/sdk-for-opencl/overview.html)

Comment: I voted to close this question because Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

This link [Intel FPGA OpenCL SDK](https://www.intel.la/content/www/xl/es/software/programmable/sdk-for-opencl/overview.html) says that you can get OpenCL design examples inside Intel SDK.

Answer (score 0):

AMD used to have good code examples. They did work quite well on older AMD GPUs. Here is what I have found:

[AMD APP SDK](https://community.amd.com/t5/opencl/where-can-i-get-an-older-version-of-amd-app-sdk/td-p/167539)

Comment: The question is off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]